# How to order by TO_CHAR(datefield,'MM-YYYY') in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to order by month and year in ascending order format. I tried to use `ORDER BY readingdate` however it resulted in eoor. Below is the query

```
 select A,B,C,(TO_CHAR(readingdate,'MM-YYYY'))mth 
 from TABLE1
 inner join TABLE2  
 left join TABLE3  
 where (Readingdate >= DATE ('2019-11-01')  
 AND Readingdate < DATE ('2020-01-31') + 1 DAY)
 group by A,B,C,TO_CHAR(readingdate,'MM-YYYY')
 order by mth;
```

Output

```
A   Mth
200  01-2020
200  11-2019
200  12-2019
```

Expected output

```
  A   Mth
 200  11-2019
 200  12-2019
 200  01-2020
```

Comment: Ordering by mth (i.e.01-2020) will never sort the way as you want it in the expected output - if you want to see it in year and month order you have to specify it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by a value that keeps the ordering you need and then transform, for example :

```
select A,B,C, TO_CHAR(mth,'MM-YYYY') mthchar
from (
 select A,B,C, last_day(readingdate) mth
 from TABLE1
 inner join TABLE2  
 left join TABLE3  
 where (Readingdate >= DATE ('2019-11-01')  
 AND Readingdate < DATE ('2020-01-31') + 1 DAY)
 group by A,B,C,last_day(readingdate)
)
order by mth;
```

Comment: this_month gives error hence I changed it to Month as the database is DB2 however it still resulted in ERROR >> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-20476, SQLSTATE=22018, SQLERRMC=DECFLOAT_FORMAT;MM-YYYY, DRIVER=3.59.81

Comment: which db2 is it ? I edited my answer with `LAST_DAY` as `THIS_MONTH` is not available on DB2LUW before 11.  I guess if you have `TO_CHAR` you also have `LAST_DAY`. `month` only gives then month number, `THIS_MONTH` and `LAST_DAY` give actual dates you can rely on to order and use in `TO_CHAR`

Comment: I realise my script was wrong, it had to be `TO_CHAR(mth,'MM-YYYY')`